# What are the specific differences between php 5.3 and php 4.9?

Tags: php

I have a few scripts in php 4.9 and I have now upgraded to php 5.3 -- where do I need to make the changes?  what should I look for trouble shooting my scripts?  Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.migration5.php

Answer (score 2):

There are very many changes. Just some documents you should read

- http://php.net/migration5
- http://php.net/migration51
- http://php.net/migration52
- http://php.net/migration53

The problem you have now is, that you update that late. It makes the migration noticable harder. However, it's even definitely worth it. PHP5 is out since 2004 and it would be easier to migrate the scripts step-by-step ("version-by-version").

I would recommend, that you just try it out. For example create a virtual machine (Virtualbox, VMWare, or such), install 5.3 there and try to run you scripts.

Comment: I understand -- I will try it and be back to you.